# Proof that Metric Spaces are Second Countable?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, second-countable

Metric spaces can be equipped with the topology given by the open sets (which in turn are defined with the help of open balls) such that **metric spaces are topological spaces**. Now, the definition of **second countable** we had in our lecture (where $(M, \tau)$ shall be a topological space):

> $(M, \tau)$ is called **second countable** if its topology has a countable basis.

Now, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second-countable_space) has this inconspicuous sentence:

> In second-countable spaces—as in metric spaces—compactness, sequential compactness, and countable compactness are all equivalent properties.

*Question*: So apparently, metric spaces are always **second countable**; however, how can we prove this? (For $M = \mathbb R^n$ it is clear, as the basis is given by open balls $B_r(p)$ with positive and rational radii $r$ and rational centres $p$, but I am not sure how the reasoning goes for arbitrary metric spaces.)

Comment: I think you're misreading "as in" as "such as." It is **not** the case that all metric spaces are second countable; consider, for example, any discrete metric space with uncountably many points.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is false. Take any uncountable set $X$ with the discrete metric $d(x,y) = 1$ for $x \ne y$, $d(x,x) = 0$.

Answer (score 6):

No it's a matter of text parsing. The Wikipedia text could (or should) have stated: consider the following properties for a space $X$:

- $X$ is compact.
- $X$ is sequentially compact.
- $X$ is countably compact.

For *general* spaces these properties are *not* equivalent (see below too).

But if we know that $X$ is (as extra info) second countable, they are equivalent.

And **also** if we know $X$ is metrisable, they are equivalent as well.

So it points out that these properties become equivalent for two distinct subclasses of spaces, the second countable ones *and* the metrisable ones.

It does *not* mean to imply that these subclasses are otherwise related by implication.

And e.g. $X=\omega_1$ is countably compact and sequentially compact and not compact (and is thus neither second countable nor metrisable) and $X=[0,1]^{\Bbb R}$ is compact but not sequentially compact (and thus also neither second countable nor metrisable). For all spaces compact *does* imply countably compact by definition, of course.

Answer (score 3):

That is not true; not every metric space is second countable.

What you have instead, as the linked Wikipedia says explicitly, is that "For metric spaces, however, the properties of being second-countable, separable ... are all *equivalent*."

See also Noah's [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4306283/proof-that-metric-spaces-are-second-countable#comment8970603_4306283) for the language interpretation of your excerpt.